# I get the same prediction for different inputs (PyTorch Neural Network regression problem)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am trying to predict the number of calories burned in exercise using an ANN in PyTorch

Dataset can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/fmendes/fmendesdat263xdemos

My issue is that the predictions that are being outputted by my model are the same for every row (I have attached an image to this post). I have tried varying the learning rates of my model to see if this would help but it hasn't. I have also tried asking ChatGPT but it hasn't given me any real solution to the problem.

Here is the code I have used so far:

#### Library Imports

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
```

#### Data Pre-Processing

```
calories = pd.read_csv("calories.csv")
excercise = pd.read_csv("exercise.csv")
df = pd.concat(\[excercise,calories\],axis=1,join="outer")


df = df.drop('User_ID',axis=1)
df.head()

data = pd.get_dummies(df,drop_first=True)

X = torch.tensor(np.array(data.drop("Calories",axis=1))).float()
y = torch.tensor(data\['Calories'\],dtype=torch.float).reshape(-1,1)
```

#### Creating ANN Class

```
class Ann_Predictor(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, n_layers, n_units):
super().__init__()
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.layers = nn.ModuleDict()
    
        self.layers["input"] = nn.Linear(7,n_units)
    
        for i in range(n_layers):
            self.layers[f"hidden{i}"] = nn.Linear(n_units,n_units)
        
        self.layers["output"] = nn.Linear(n_units,1)
    
    def forward(self, x):
    
        # forward pass
    
        x = self.layers['input'](x)
    
        for i in range(self.n_layers):
            x = F.relu(self.layers[f"hidden{i}"](x))
    
        x = self.layers["output"](x)
    
        return x
```

#### Function to instantiate Model, Loss Function and Optimizer

```
def create_model():

    ann = Ann_Predictor(3,8)
    loss_func = nn.MSELoss()
    learning_rate = 0.005
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(ann.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)
    
    return ann, loss_func, optimizer
```

#### Model Training & Predictions

```
numepochs = 500
losses = torch.zeros(numepochs)

ann, loss_func, optimizer = create_model()

for epoch in range(numepochs):
y_hat = ann(X)
loss = loss_func(y_hat, y)
losses\[epoch\] = loss

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

# Predicting Using Model

predictions  = ann(X)
print(predictions)
```

Here is an image of the predictions output (same value everywhere): [Predictions Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xITzK.png)

As stated earlier I have tried varying the learning rates and asking ChatGPT but have found no solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue, for me increasing the batch size from 256 to 2048 avoided that error, so I also believe it might have to do with hyper parameter tunings and like mentioned above try normalization. Each model depends on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the same output irrespective of whatever input you are giving to the network, it seems that the network has learned a constant value which minimizes the loss function for all the inputs. In other words, the network hasn't "learned" anything. It would have been useful if you could also plot the loss curves.

Also, from the code snippets you shared and looking at the dataset, it seems like you are just training on the raw input data without doing any form of pre-processing. Your network, right now, takes in a 7-dimensional input, the raw values of which are different units, ranges etc. (For example, age and height have a completely different range of values). It will be very difficult to train a neural network like this. You could start with normalising/standardising all your input values to be within a common range eg. [0,1] or [-1,1].

Answer (score 0):

Got similar issue for a regression problem using CNN. It works in Keras, but not in Torch. Followed other suggestions such as learning rate, batch size, normalization etc.

Turns out Torch is using Lecun initialization by default.
For relu, it is best to use Kaiming He initialization and it solved the problem for me.

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
nn.init.kaiming_normal_(self.conv1.weight)
```

Also refer to this:
https://adityassrana.github.io/blog/theory/2020/08/26/Weight-Init.html